# How to generate client code using springdoc-openapi-maven-plugin and swagger-codegen-maven-plugin?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, swagger, openapi

My goal is to **generate Spring Boot REST Client using OpenAPI 3.0**.

I would like to **first** generate the OpenAPI specification file (springdoc-openapi-maven-plugin) of my API and **then** generate the client code from this file (swagger-codegen-maven-plugin) using Maven.

My problem is that **swagger-codegen-maven-plugin** is executed before **springdoc-openapi-maven-plugin**. So, the output file generated by **springdoc-openapi-maven-plugin** does not exist when **swagger-codegen-maven-plugin** executes.

How to execute **springdoc-openapi-maven-plugin** before **swagger-codegen-maven-plugin** given the following Maven build plugins configuration?

My Maven build plugin configuration:

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>pre-integration-test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>start</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>post-integration-test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>stop</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
                <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>integration-test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <apiDocsUrl>myServerUrl:myPort/v3/api-docs</apiDocsUrl>
                    <outputFileName>openApiFile.json</outputFileName>
                    <outputDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</outputDir>
                    <skip>false</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.swagger.codegen.v3</groupId>
                <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.24</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/openApiFile.json</inputSpec>
                            <language>typescript-angular</language>
                            <configOptions>
                                <sourceFolder>src/gen/java/main</sourceFolder>
                            </configOptions>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that **springdoc-openapi-maven-plugin** is executed during `integration-test` phase while **swagger-codegen-maven-plugin** default phase is `generate-sources` which is executed before `integration-test` in the build lifecycle.

I just specified a phase for **swagger-codegen-maven-plugin** which is after `integration-test`: `<phase>post-integration-test</phase>`.